# inject info into search bar jQuery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What is the best way to inject the content within the li's into the text box on hover or click? I suppose like autocomplete for a search page.

```
<form>
    <input id="search" type="text" size="75" maxlength="60" placeholder="search stuff saturday" value="">
</form>

<ul>
    <li class="red-red">stuff here</li>
    <li class="red-red">more things</li>
    <li class="red-red">ginormous things</li>
</ul>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is about helping to solve problems, not writing other peoples' code.

Comment: @flomei I've been trying to set variables for the innerhtml of the li's and passing that into the val of the text.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, that will help people.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you can use `.val()` function to set the value of an `<input>`, and `.text()` function to get the value of the `<li>`s:

```
$("li.red-red").click(function() {
    $("input#search").val($(this).text());
});
```

See working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jlam55555/jLghja6g/) on JSFiddle.net.

You can do this with jQuery's `.hover()` as well, but its syntax is a bit different (but beware: you need handlers for both the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events).

---

Seeing your comment, there's a big change to be made. jQuery selectors (or JS, for that matter), only work on *existing* elements.

Therefore, for the code to work, you have to put it *after* your dynamic creation. The problem is when you need to add list items after the page loads.

If so, then you should probably apply the `.click()` handler to each `<li>` as you create it, like so:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {  // this is my "dynamic creation"
    var li = $("<li>");
    li.addClass("red-red");
    li.text("stuff here " + i);
    li.click(function() {      // put `click()` handler on EXISTING li (variable)
        $("input#search").val($(this).text());
    });
    $("ul").append(li);
}
```

See [updated working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jlam55555/jLghja6g/1/).

Comment: This works great in examples, but when I try clicking my li.red-red (which is dynamically driven results if that matters) I am not able to click. Thank you for the heads up on how to go about this problem.

Comment: @newneub See my answer. The dynamic-adding does make matter.

Comment: @newneub If the answer helps, please accept. If not, feedback?

Comment: Jonathan:  Your answer put me on the right track but it didn't work for my purposes. I found that I needed to delegate the handler by using the function I used above.

Answer (score 0):

what I ended up doing was using:

```
 $(document).on('click','li.red-red', function(){
        var foo = $('input#search').val($(this).html());
    });
```

This works. The only problem I have now is that the html transferred from li.red-red to input#search adds +++++ to the front and back of the url when running a search based off the 'autocomplete' functionality.